# Altium OutJob Red Arrow

Tags: altium

I'm using Altium v.20.2.4

When linking the Gerber files to the folder structure in Altium, I get a red arrow. I don't know why, and nothing seems wrong with the Gerbers when looking at them in View mate. The project compile with no errors etc..

Does anyone know why the arrow is red rather than green (as it should be)?

[image: Screenshot of Variant Choice]

Answer (score 0):

The red arrow relates to a mismatch between the paper size in the selected option and the output container.

From [Altium's documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/streamlining-generation-of-manufacturing-data-with-output-jobs#!linking-outputs-to-output-containers-and-print-jobs) (emphasis mine):

> When the target for an applicable print-based output is changed from a PDF output container to a physical printer (print job), it is quite possible that the paper size defined for the generator - through the relevant properties dialog (right-click, Page Setup) - may not be supported by the target medium. **In this case, the connecting arrow from generator to medium is colored red when the output is enabled.** You will be prevented from previewing/printing in this state. You can either change the paper size for the output generator, and thus return the connecting arrow to a green state, before the applicable output can be successfully generated. Or, simply change the target medium to one that does support your chosen paper size. Where a paper size mismatch exists, and you opt to change the paper size for the configured output, using the Page Setup command for the output will bring up an information dialog. This alerts you to the issue, and notifies you that the paper sizing has been restored to its default. What this means is that the paper size drop-down in the configurator dialog is loaded afresh with the standard set of paper sizes supported by the target printer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. in this case however I am generating Gerbers so I'm now too sure why PDF paper size are relevant to this issue.